# facebook app for wordpress

Tags: android, facebook-comments, facebook-social-plugins

I installed the facebook app for wordpress so that I can make posts in my wp site to show up in fb, but I have gotten a little lost in creating the app that I think is required. Currently I am getting this error message and the information being requested. I am not even sure I want, but if it is so that I can post using my android then the answer is no, I do not want to post to my WP site to display in FB.

#### Error

> You have enabled a Facebook Login integration for your app, but have not specified the Key Hashes. For security reasons, the Facebook application will not interact with any native application that does not have a signature that matches a corresponding key hash.
>
> You have enabled a Page Tab integration for your app, but have not specified a Page Tab URL.

Comment: if I have mislabeled/tagged this I am sorry not sure how to use the systeme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to complete the Android / iOS settings on the page. You just need to fill in the Web address and the application domain. If you remove the settings you don't need it should work (click on the x at the end of the box to delete the settings).

Comment: ok thanks what about the page tab and page tab image do I really need that as I state earlier I just want my post in my wp site to show on my fb page

Comment: You can ignore that section too, unless you want to include your blog on a Fan page. Like I said, just fill in the "Website with Facebook Login" section.